# grails 3 url and grails no controller find

Tags: grails

When I uses grails2, the Url will be

http://localhost:8080/myApp/controllerName

when I use grails 3.

The Url is http://localhost:8080/controllerName

No myapp any more. it is designed?

Question 2: After I generate-all with Restful domain in grails, it always say

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built due to "RequestEnvironmentController [in [Working copy] RequestEnvironment.groovy [in test.environment.manager [in grails-app/domain [in test-environment-manager]]]] does not exist". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent

the it can only compile 83%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No myapp any more. it is designed?

Yes.  The root context by default is now `'/'`.  If you want to override that you can by setting the context path in `grails-app/conf/application.yml`.

```
server:
    'context-path': '/myApp'
```

Comment: good. This works. Do you know the question 2? why there is always an error and always 83% compile?

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/641.  You shouldn't post separate unrelated questions together here on StackOverflow.  You should post them as separate questions because they are unrelated.

Comment: There are comments about the `context-path` setting at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.3/guide/gettingStarted.html#aHelloWorldExample.